# Configure all AWS Managed rules in AWS Config through Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-config

I have a requirement to select all the rules in AWS Config while deploying the resources in newly created account through Cloudformation. But I don't know how to select all the AWS Managed rules as in Console through Cloudformation. Any help would be very helpful.
[image]

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Enable AWS Config

```
Parameters:
  AllSupported:
    Type: String
    Default: True
    Description: Indicates whether to record all supported resource types.
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False

  IncludeGlobalResourceTypes:
    Type: String
    Default: True
    Description: Indicates whether AWS Config records all supported global resource types.
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False

  ResourceTypes:
    Type: List<String>
    Description: A list of valid AWS resource types to include in this recording group, such as AWS::EC2::Instance or AWS::CloudTrail::Trail.
    Default: <All>

  DeliveryChannelName:
    Type: String
    Default: <Generated>
    Description: The name of the delivery channel.

  Frequency:
    Type: String
    Default: 24hours
    Description: The frequency with which AWS Config delivers configuration snapshots.
    AllowedValues:
      - 1hour
      - 3hours
      - 6hours
      - 12hours
      - 24hours



Conditions:
  IsAllSupported: !Equals
    - !Ref AllSupported
    - True
  IsGeneratedDeliveryChannelName: !Equals
    - !Ref DeliveryChannelName
    - <Generated>


Mappings:
  Settings:
    FrequencyMap:
      1hour   : One_Hour
      3hours  : Three_Hours
      6hours  : Six_Hours
      12hours : Twelve_Hours
      24hours : TwentyFour_Hours

Resources:

  ConfigBucket:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256

  ConfigBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref ConfigBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: AWSConfigBucketPermissionsCheck
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - config.amazonaws.com
            Action: s3:GetBucketAcl
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ConfigBucket}"
          - Sid: AWSConfigBucketDelivery
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - config.amazonaws.com
            Action: s3:PutObject
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ConfigBucket}/AWSLogs/${AWS::AccountId}/*"
          - Sid: AWSConfigBucketSecureTransport
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Effect: Deny
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ConfigBucket}"
              - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ConfigBucket}/*"
            Principal: "*"
            Condition:
              Bool:
                aws:SecureTransport:
                  false

 

  ConfigRecorderRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - config.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWS_ConfigRole"

  ConfigRecorder:
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigurationRecorder
    DependsOn:
      - ConfigBucketPolicy
    Properties:
      RoleARN: !GetAtt ConfigRecorderRole.Arn
      RecordingGroup:
        AllSupported: !Ref AllSupported
        IncludeGlobalResourceTypes: !Ref IncludeGlobalResourceTypes
        ResourceTypes: !If
          - IsAllSupported
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
          - !Ref ResourceTypes

  ConfigDeliveryChannel:
    Type: AWS::Config::DeliveryChannel
    DependsOn:
      - ConfigBucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Name: !If
        - IsGeneratedDeliveryChannelName
        - !Ref AWS::NoValue
        - !Ref DeliveryChannelName
      ConfigSnapshotDeliveryProperties:
        DeliveryFrequency: !FindInMap
          - Settings
          - FrequencyMap
          - !Ref Frequency
      S3BucketName: !Ref ConfigBucket

  
  ConfigRuleForVolumeTags:
    DependsOn: ConfigRecorder
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
    Properties: 
      InputParameters: 
        tag1Key: CostCenter
      Scope: 
        ComplianceResourceTypes: 
          - "AWS::EC2::Volume"
      Source: 
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: "REQUIRED_TAGS"
  # Like this I need all the AWS Managed rules
```

Comment: @Marcin, still it's unclear. Actually, I saw a project in GIT [link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-rules/tree/master/aws-config-conformance-packs). It has the CFN Scripts for config similar functionality, but it is having more than 1.5k lines of code which makes my main infra CFN code clumsy and difficult to understand for someone who is new. Do you know any CLI command to trigger all the rules, if so it would be very helpful as I will implement them in a python/bash script after deploying all the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. There are no loops in cloudformation. But you could create a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) if you want such a functionality.